# Any advantage of having a second index with included columns on a primary key?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, index, index-tuning

I'm reviewing our database and noticed that on a particular table we have the following indexes:

**Table**:

```
Col1    INT IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key
Col2    INT
...
about 15 more columns
....
ColN   VARCHAR(50)
....
another 10 more columns
```

In addition to the standard primary key clustered index on `Col1`, we also have the following index:

```
create nonclustered index [iTable-Col1] ON [dbo].[Table1]
(
    Col1
)
include ( ColN )
```

We regularly search by `Col1` and want to only retrieve `ColN`. This index does get used as it is the smallest index that contains all of the data required to satisfy the query.

My question is, does this index add any benefit to SQL Server? Would we be better off dropping it and just doing a search on the clustered index?

My only thought is that this index is much smaller than the clustered index (25mb vs 300mb) which may make searching and/or caching faster.

Server is SQL Server 2012 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Your question includes the answer: (*"My only thought is that this index is much smaller than the clustered index (25mb vs 300mb) which may make searching and/or caching faster."*)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of the time, this type of index is only useful for index *scans* against those columns.

The index tree structure above the leaf level will usually be very similar in terms of tree levels, so if that's the case, there's little or no performance difference in navigating the tree for *seek* operations (that don't also scan). If you want to learn the basics of index internals, I have a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITcOiLSfVJQ) that will help you.

Anyways, back to the scans. The reasons why this index would be useful are much less about the index itself, and more about why *not* to scan the clustered index (or keep those data pages in memory). If the other columns make the table relatively wide (based on the sizes you gave, I would say they do, although it's unclear how large this table is in the context of the entire database), the narrow index *may* be of benefit in some cases. Frequent scans (or seeks on many different key values) will tend to keep the entire index in memory, so the larger the index, the less memory space there will be for other objects, and of course this will incur more I/O if the buffer pool is cold.

Although it's somewhat of a rare use case (I've done it once or maybe twice that I can remember), the biggest benefit of this type of index is it will greatly help queries that want to use a merge join to join this table. (Note: optimize the query *first* if an index scan isn't appropriate!) In the query plan, a scan of the clustered index, or a scan and sort of a nonclustered index before a merge join can give an indication of when this might be a good idea. But again, this is rare. The query should be executed frequently enough, or the base table expensive enough to keep stuck in memory (i.e., you don't *need* it there all the time), to justify the extra storage and maintenance for the index.

If you're unsure *how* this index is being used right now, check the DMV [`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx). Bear in mind that the counts are reset on server restart, so if you're considering dropping the index, make sure it isn't useful during the *entire business cycle*.

Answer (score 0):

Let SQL Server answer your question, if the index is useful the Query Optimizer will use it, otherwise it won't.

Comment: SQL will always use the smallest index that satisfies a query. If Index 1 and Index 2 both satisfy the query but index one is smaller then it will use that. This doesn't necessarily mean we should have both?